# Save all contents in ListBox to .txt file

Tags: c#

I am trying to save all contents in a ListBox to a .txt file. I have the following code:

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     const string sPath = "save.txt";

     System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
     SaveFile.WriteLine(listBox1.Items);
     SaveFile.ToString();
     SaveFile.Close();

     MessageBox.Show("Programs saved!");
}
```

But when I test it the code works but and it acts like it saved the file but when I go into my File Explorer, I cannot see the file anywhere.

Does anyone have any answers

Comment: specify an absolute path to `sPath`, then it will be easier to find the "save.txt" file.

Comment: BTW, if you do find "save.txt" the contents will be "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection".  So your code is not OK too 

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the explicit path. Example:

`const string sPath = @"C:\MyFolder\save.txt";`

Comment: Good spot! Alternatively could do ```const string sPath = "C:\\MyFolder\\save.txt";```

Answer (score 0):

What u have to do?

First:

You need a StreamWriter, u done it right. This StreamWriter needs a Path, you did this too.

Second:

You want all Items of your listbox, so use foreach. You havent done this.

Third: Close the Stream, you done it too. Use using instead of close , its better :) do the same :)

Where i find the file? Go to your Project right in Visual Studio right click on it -> open in windows explorer -> bin -> Debug and your text file is their. If you dont give a absolute path, the saved data is always next to your .exe.

Solution:

```
  string path = "save.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(s);
            }
        };
```